# File is not submitting correctly, nested objects Django Models

Tags: reactjs, django, serialization, file-upload

I am trying to create a method that will send a created Model object to the server, validate it and save it. But this Model has another Model nested in it. The Model that is nested in it has an image file that also needs to be validate, but everytime I submit it says that file is not a file and not the correct encoding type.

The error is Bad Request 400 error. It shows that "cover" is just {} instead of the data that I gave it. I'm not sure how to make sure cover is given the correct data.

**Code**

```
async function createFile(input) {
    let response = await fetch(input);
    let data = await response.blob();
    let metadata = {
        type: 'image/jpg'
    };
    // let name = input.substring(input.lastIndexOf('/')+1,input.length);

    return new File([data], input, metadata);
}
const updated_items = async () => {
    let a = props.items
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        let img = await createFile(props.items[i].cover)
        let newimg = {
            "lastModified": img.lastModified,
            "lastModifiedDate" : img.lastModifiedDate,
            "name" : img.name,
            "size" :img.size,
            "type": img.type
        }
        a[i].cover = img

    }
    return a
}

const onAddClick = async ()  => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    let items = await updated_items()
    // formData.append('about', about);
    // formData.append('name', cname);
    // formData.append('worn',date);
    // items.forEach(item => {
    //     formData.append(`items[]`, JSON.stringify(item));
    // });

    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
        console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
    }
    // console.log(items)
    const data = {
        "about":  about,
        "name": cname,
        "worn": date,
        "items": items,
    }
    dispatch(addOutfit(data));

};
```

**Serializers**

```
class ClothingItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     super(ClothingItemSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #     user = self.context['request'].user
    #     self.fields['ctype'] = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',queryset=ClothingType.objects.filter(user=user))
    ctype =serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='name',queryset=ClothingType.objects.all())
    cover = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ClothingItem
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'worn', 'ctype', 'location', 'cover')

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     types_data = validated_data.pop('ctype')
    #     item = ClothingItem.objects.create(**validated_data)
    #     for type_data in types_data:
    #         ClothingType.objects.create()

class OutfitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ClothingItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Outfit
        fields = ('id', 'name','about','worn','items')
```

**Models**

```
class ClothingItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    worn = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    ctype = models.ForeignKey(ClothingType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Outfit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    about = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    worn = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ClothingItem)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']
```